# iOS 11, xCode 9, Swift 4 Navigation Bar Button Not Touchable if Placed Inside a View?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uinavigationbar, xcode9, swift4

In my iOS app's Navigation Bar, I have Buttons placed inside a View. Prior to iOS 11/Xcode 9, the buttons were completely touchable and interactable. After upgrading, this is no longer the case. Also, I'd like to mention that my app that was compiled in Xcode 7 / Swift 3 (currently in the App Store) when run on an iOS 11 device, the buttons in the Navigation Bar work and are touchable.

There was another post about the same problem in which someone found a solution by not embedding a View into the Navigation Bar, and instead placing two BarButtonItems next to each other on the Left or Right item slots. However, I need to have two buttons in the Center portion of the Navigation Bar, and this does not support placing more than 1 Button without an embedded View.

I have also tried referencing the embedded View and adding a UITapGestureRecognizer, but it also did not work. (Perhaps I'm implementing this incorrectly?)

Is this an iOS compiling bug? Has anyone figured a way around this?

Comment: I ran into the same problem.  I found that they are still press-able with a hard or 3D press.  Still, I haven't figured out how to restore the normal press.

Comment: I solved my issue by removing a tap `UITapGestureRecognizer` which I had assigned to the view controller.  The TapRecognizer was capturing the navigation bar item taps.  The 3D presses were still getting through, but the taps were being re-directed.

Comment: Do you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `UITapGestureRecognizer`, then make sure it isn't capturing the navigation bar taps.